# CKEditor - Allowing MathML Code

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, mathml

I need to allow for the adding of MathML code to CKEditor.  When I add some to our installation, CKEditor blows the code away.  Others have mentioned the wiris plugin and we are using wiris to create the MathML, however once in CKeditor it's rendered useless.

We use MathJax for consistent rendering across browsers, however I can't get to that point without the MathML code.

Answer (score 0):

WIRIS plugin stores formulas as MathML in the database, they are rendered into images on the CKeditor window. You can edit the MathML editing the source code (i.e. with CKeditor's source code dialog). You can also edit the MathML using Ctrl+Shift+X in the WIRIS editor window.

You can find more details on how WIRIS stores and renders the MathML at http://www.wiris.com/en/plugins/docs/full-mathml-mode

Comment: What I'm looking for is straight MathML output so I can render the results with MathJax....unaltered MathML is what I'm looking for.  I don't seem to be able to do that within CKEditor (Whether I put in MathML code myself or use the Wiris plugin).

Comment: If you use WIRIS plugin the content within the CKeditor edit window will be rendered into images by our plugin so you can edit the formulas. However, as the content is stored as MathML you can later render it on presentation time by MathJax.

Answer (score 0):

On the [ckeditor demo page](http://ckeditor.com/demo#widgets), they have an example that uses the [Mathematical Formulas](http://ckeditor.com/addon/mathjax) widget. In this example, although the instructions mention only TeX, I can paste MathML into the Source view. It's rendered by MathJax, and it remains MathML.

Comment: Hm.  Let me give that a shot.  I have that plugin. - Can you point me to the exact plugin.  What's the plugin folder name?  I'm trying all of them and none work as you mention.

Comment: Actually I've never used the Mathematical Formulas widget except in the demo page, both of which are linked in my earlier reply. Not sure what the plugin folder name is. Sorry I'm not of more help.

Answer (score 0):

[MathEx](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/MathEx) Plugin supports mathml and latex on CKEditor,
you can download MathEx from the CKEditor addon to your plugin folder and configure according to it

```
config.extraPlugins = 'MathEx';
```